# Hide server exceptions from users

Tags: spring, rest, jboss

Our security team has instructed that we hide the app server from our users in the event of an exception.

Our application is a rest web service. I have a several services. If someone access our endpoint that's not a valid service, I want to display a generic message.

The application is built on spring 4.2.x/Apache cfx 2.7.x and Jackson 2.4.x. The app server is JBoss EAP 6.2.0.GA (AS 7.3.0.Final-redhat-14).

In the web.xml

```
<error-page>
    <location>/error</location>
</error-page>
```

This seems return a html page. Is there a way to return a json?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

You may add error URL pointing to a Servlet/Controller and from that handler return JSON.

```
<error-page>
    <location>/error</location>
</error-page>

@RestController
public class ErrorController
{
    @RequestMapping("/error)
    public JsonError handleError()
    {
       //construct JsonError 
       return new JsonError ();
    }
}
```